# MVC ViewModel Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using C# MVC with Razor.

Say if I have a view that shows a list, drop down, and 2 text boxes.
Should all of this information be kept in 1 class which will then be pass to my view?

Comment: That really depends what that data is. If the data in all the components is closely related - for example, different sub-fields for the same field - than yes, it's a good idea to put it all in a single class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't stress enough the importance of using ViewModels for passing data from your controllers to the view. As stated in your question, you're doing this already which is an excellent start!

So .. this is how I would do it.

```
public class IndexViewModel // or DetailsViewModel or whatever the Action Method is
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public SelectList DropDownBox { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // Textbox 1
    public string Description { get; set; } // Textbox 2
}
```

OK. so lets see what I've done.

I've passed all the information which the `View` requires. Nothing more, nothing less. Just the -exact- info.

The `Foos` are a list of `foo` which you can then loop through to render. (PRO TIP: Use DisplayTemplates to render out your custom type / collections of custom types).

I've also suggested in passing in a `SelectList` which is the drop down contents, etc. Some people don't like this (which is fine). Instead they pass in a collection of their items to render in the drop down list, but i personally find that far too leaky. The key reason why we have `ViewModels` is so we can *test* these things.

Finally, I have a single property per text box.

*So in summary, I put all the information in a single `ViewModel`. This view model could contain other classes (exposed via properties). But yes - **you want one ViewModel per view**.*

Answer (score 0):

Well from the projects I have done, I would suggest keeping all the information in one class but it all depends upon the data, as stated by Idan Arye, you are using. From what you are asking I would suggest taking a look at msdn which is great resource for C#. Hopefully that helped

Answer (score 0):

It depends how big will be your model, but yes you can keep them in one class

For e.g. If as simple as Employee with 3 as shown below then keep it in 1 class. But if it 3 -4 times bigger then this and have more complex data fields then try to keep them in separate classes

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var employeeModel = new Employee
       {
           FirstName = "Hat",
           LastName = "Soft",
           Departments = new BindingList<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Accounts", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Human Resource", Value = "2"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Operations", Value = "3"}
            }
       };

        return View(employeeModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are really asking should I use a view model?

Similar to... [Should I use a view model for just two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716673/should-i-use-a-view-model-for-just-two-objects)

IMHO view models are often a nice fit when working with MVC and Razor.

Ultimately it is up to you and the decision really depends on your model among other factors. For instance If the bits required for your view are ultimately sourced from different entities in your model then one might argue the answer is yes and you should consider using view models because a single view model can be tailored to suit your view.

Basically view models can help keep your views clean. The main implication to usually consider is the inevitable mapping logic that is required for mapping domain entities to view models and the other way around (e.g. During a GET or POST). [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is an example of a library you could use to cut down on the mapping code. In my experience it can work well as long as your mapping logic isn't terribly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, depends what the page is for, if you are to show the properties of a domain object in which case you should consider have a special object for the view (e.g. View Model) your class would the domain's object class (e.g. User) and at some point your View Model's (e.g. UserViewModel).

You can also of course, make use of Value Objects / DTO for carrying compound objects, thus, you'll have to create the correspondent classes that are not domain specific but still needed to transport data across your system, from the DAL to your views.

At the end you'll always need a View Model Class, which would correspond to domain object or a custom DTO / Value Object to present your data in the view.

Hope this helps a bit.